# How to place image at the bottom of the titlepage

Tags: graphics, titles

I would like to place a picture at the bottom of the titlepage and include some text on the picture and above it. As the sample attached demonstrates.

[image]

Comment: \usepackage[abs]{overpic} address the text over the picture and I have tried unsuccessfully placing the image in title page with packages:titlepic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the `eso-pic` package:

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

The command is along the lines of

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \includegraphics[width=ADJUST-HERE]{IMAGE.png}%
    }%
}
```

This will render IMAGE.png in the background in the lower left on the page where you issue the command.

(The comment indicator % is used to prevent newlines and spaces from messing up the picture.)

To achieve text above the picture, typeset your text normally and adjust with `\vspace` and `\hspace` until it fits.